# React Native: Swipe Back (left to right) to close Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog

Background:

1. I'm using React Native Modal (`import { Modal } from 'react-native';`) to show a Modal.
2. I'm not using React Native Navigation in the project.
3. Did you see in some apps, when a modal is open, that you can do a Swipe from the very Left border to the Right, and the modal get closed?
4. AFAIK, React Native Nativation do it by default.

Question:
How can I replicate the behavior of closing the React Native Modal by doing a Swipe from the very left border of the device to the right?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using react-native-swipe-gestures and dismiss the modal on swipeRight. More details here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-gestures